# How to deserialize an array containing a list?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I would like to deserialize an array containing some things and 3 List.
The program works fine except for List. The lists are created but they contain nothing !

Can you help me ?

Here is how the xml file looks like :

```
<blind>
  <folder>C:\Users\Michael\Desktop\BT 1 normal\Programme BT\</folder>
  <nombre_titres>25</nombre_titres>
  <numero></numero>
  <theme></theme>
  <heure_debut></heure_debut>
  <mdp>a</mdp>
  <lien></lien>
  <playlist>
    <extrait>
      <artiste>Abba</artiste>
      <titre>Take a chance on me</titre>
      <PointAT>1.25</PointAT>
      <PointA>0.5</PointA>
      <PointT>0.5</PointT>
      <JoueursAT>
        <joueurAT>Ahkayaqua</joueurAT>
        <joueurAT>Angelene</joueurAT>
      </JoueursAT>
      <JoueursA>
        <joueurA></joueurA>
      </JoueursA>
      <JoueursT>
        <joueurT></joueurT>
      </JoueursT>
    </extrait>
<extrait>
....
</extrait>
 </playlist>
</blind>
```

My code to deserialize :

```
XElement xmle;
xmle = XElement.Load(_folder + "Blind.xml");
textBox1.Text = xmle.Element("numero").Value;
textBox4.Text = xmle.Element("theme").Value;
textBox3.Text = xmle.Element("heure_debut").Value;
textBox5.Text = xmle.Element("lien").Value;
textBox2.Text = xmle.Element("mdp").Value;                    
extraits = (from ex in xmle.Element("playlist").Elements("extrait")
            select new Extrait
                (ex.Element("artiste").Value,
                 ex.Element("titre").Value,
                 0,
                 0,
                 0,
                 (from jat in ex.Element("JoueursAT").Elements("JoueurAT")
                  select jat.Element("JoueurAT").Value).ToList(),
                 (from ja in ex.Element("JoueursA").Elements("JoueurA")
                  select ja.Element("JoueurA").Value).ToList(),
                 (from jt in ex.Element("JoueursT").Elements("JoueurT")
                  select jt.Element("JoueurT").Value).ToList())).ToArray();
```

And here is my class:

```
public class Extrait
{
    private String _Artiste;
    private String _Titre;
    private double _PointA;
    private double _PointT;
    private double _PointAT;
    private List<String> _JoueurA;
    private List<String> _JoueurT;
    private List<String> _JoueurAT;

    public String Artiste
    {
        get { return _Artiste; }
        set { _Artiste = value; }
    }

    public String Titre
    {
        get { return _Titre; }
        set { _Titre = value; }
    }

    public Double PointA
    {
        get { return _PointA; }
        set { _PointA = value; }
    }

    public Double PointT
    {
        get { return _PointT; }
        set { _PointT = value; }
    }

    public Double PointAT
    {
        get { return _PointAT; }
        set { _PointAT = value; }
    }

    public List<String> JoueurA
    {
        get { return _JoueurA; }
        set { _JoueurA = value; }
    }

    public List<String> JoueurT
    {
        get { return _JoueurT; }
        set { _JoueurT = value; }
    }

    public List<String> JoueurAT
    {
        get { return _JoueurAT; }
        set { _JoueurAT = value; }
    }

    public Extrait(String Artiste, String Titre, Double PointA, Double PointT, Double PointAT, List<String> JoueurAT, List<String> JoueurA, List<String> JoueurT)
    {
        _Artiste = Artiste;
        _Titre = Titre;
        _PointA = PointA;
        _PointT = PointT;
        _PointAT = PointAT;
        _JoueurAT = JoueurAT;
        _JoueurA = JoueurA;
        _JoueurT = JoueurT;
    }
}
```

Well, I've tried many possibilities, but none worked !

Comment: You using xml to linq and not deserializing. To deserialize xml to object use XmlSerializer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your actual xml, then look at the inner tags - they start with lower letter. Your xml have `<joueurAT>` while you selecting elements with name `.Elements("JoueurAT")` - node names are case-sensitive.

Your code should look like:

```
extraits = (from ex in xmle.Element("playlist").Elements("extrait")
        select new Extrait
            (ex.Element("artiste").Value,
             ex.Element("titre").Value,
             0,
             0,
             0,
             (from jat in ex.Element("JoueursAT").Elements("joueurAT")
              select jat.Value).ToList(),
             (from ja in ex.Element("JoueursA").Elements("joueurA")
              select ja.Value).ToList(),
             (from jt in ex.Element("JoueursT").Elements("joueurT")
              select jt.Value).ToList())).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

This should fix it. Basically the default behaviour is to use two-level nesting for lists (meaning it defaults to `[XmlArray]` plus `[XmlArrayItem]`; you only have one-level here, so you need to tell it.

```
[XmlElement]
public List<String> JoueurA
{
    get { return _JoueurA; }
    set { _JoueurA = value; }
}
[XmlElement]
public List<String> JoueurT
{
    get { return _JoueurT; }
    set { _JoueurT = value; }
}
[XmlElement]
public List<String> JoueurAT
{
    get { return _JoueurAT; }
    set { _JoueurAT = value; }
}
```

Btw; you might find it more convenient to use something like auto-properties here; an example for both regular properties and lists:

```
public double PointAT {get;set;}
[XmlElement]
public List<string> JoueurA {get;} = new List<string>();
```

This is a lot more convenient than messing with all the fields yourself.

You probably also want to make sure you have a public parameterless constructor; frankly I'd just *remove* the custom constructor (in which case: a public parameterless constructor is included for free), but otherwise - I'd just add:

```
public Extrait() {}
```

Comment: OP does not actually do deserialization, so attributes will not work in this case.Check "deserialization" code

Answer (score 0):

The change is needed in the blind class

```
   [XmlRoot("blind")]
    public class Blind
    {
        [XmlArray("playlist")]
        [XmlArrayItem("extrait")]
        public List<Extrait> extrait { get; set; }
    }
    public class Extrait
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
(from jat in ex.Element("JoueursAT").Elements("JoueurAT")
 select jat.Element("JoueurAT").Value).ToList()
```

should become

```cs
(from jat in ex.Element("JoueursAT").Elements("joueurAT")
 select jat.Value).ToList()
```

I'm not sure if C#'s XML library is case sensitive when it comes to token names, but when in doubt, it's better to play it safe.
You also tried to access an element "joueurAT" when making your select despite having actually looped over them already, so you can just access the `Value` property directly.

Also instead of using LINQ the way you do, you could try the extension methods, which tend to be more readable :

```cs
xmle.Element("playlist").Elements("extrait")
    .Select(ex => new Extrait
    {
        Artiste = ex.Element("artiste").Value,
        Titre = ex.Element("titre").Value,
        PointA = 0,
        PointT = 0,
        PointAT = 0,
        JoueurA = ex.Element("JoueursAT").Elements("joueurAT").Select(jat => jat.Value).ToList(),
        JoueurT = ex.Element("JoueursA").Elements("joueurA").Select(ja => ja.Value).ToList(),
        JoueurAT = ex.Element("JoueursT").Elements("joueurT").Select(jt => jt.Value).ToList()
    });
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but it gives an error message : "There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'Artiste' ...."

Comment: Ha my bad, I modified the class Extrait a bit to use auto-properties, so that may be the issue